# WordPress Custom Menu Order Not Saving

Tags: wordpress, menu

I've been working on a WordPress site for 3 months or so and I'm now all of a sudden experiencing a strange bug. When I reorder a menu under Appearance > Menus and hit save, it doesn't actually save the new location where I dragged the menu item to.

I can add new items, I can delete items and re-add them, but if I try to rearrange them and hit save they don't move.

Its a multi-lingual site using WPML and Avada. Everything up to date. Has anyone experienced this before? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: http://sevenspark.com/wordpress/menu-item-limit

Comment: Thanks Vasim, I'm not sure this is the answer though. My PHP.ini file is set pretty high already. 10,000 and I don't have thaaaaat many links in the menu. It seems if I remove some items and re-add them it sorta fixes it but its not a sure thing. It seems to be putting things in its own order sometimes.

Comment: can you try with default theme?/

Comment: Just tried the 2017 theme. I tried to rearrange a link and then hit save and it just reverts back to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem with some plugins, can you please try the same by deactivating the plugins.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Our site is on Pantheon so I will create a multi-dev site so I can disable the plugins without fear of breaking anything meaningful and report back.